# JavaScript counterpart to JQuery's .on( multiple mouse events)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert an old app from JQuery to JavaScript.

What would be the JavaScript counterpart to this JQuery line of code?

```
  this.element = el.on('click mouseenter mouseleave', (this._handleMouse.bind(this), this));
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note , not certain about purpose of second `this` at

```
(this._handleMouse.bind(this), this)
```

?

---

Try creating an object having properties `events` array , `element` `DOM` element, `_handleMouse` event handler , utilizing `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate `events` array attaching `event` to `settingas.element` , with `Function.prototype.bind()` set to `settings.element`

```js
var settings = {
  events: ["click", "mouseenter", "mouseleave"],
  element: document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
  _handleMouse: function(e) {
    console.log(this.textContent, e.type)
  }
};

settings.events.forEach(function(event) {
  settings.element["on" + event] = settings._handleMouse.bind(settings.element)
})
```

```html
<div>abc</div>
```

Comment: That's not equivalent to jQuery's `.on`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this one maybe

```
object.onclick=function(){your code on click};
```

Works the same with mouseenter and mouseleave.
You can also give a function as value instead of making one without name.